# Parallel compile a huge C file (preferrably with gcc)

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I have one huge C file. Within the file, there is a giant struct (~>1million lines). Is there a way to parallel compile this file using additional cores?

Edit: Sorry, after reviewing my code and my question, the actual giant thing is not "struct", rather, it's the struct array...

Comment: 1 million code lines? That's one gigantic struct.

Comment: If it is only a large giant `struct` then there isn't much to compile in parallel?

Comment: I don't think there is.  Paralleling compilation (preprocessing, token parsing, semantic processing, code generation, optimization) is not easily made parallel.  This is very similar to the problem of refactoring one woman giving birth in nine months into nine women giving birth to a baby in one month.

Comment: @siglettervariables: If there is no other way, I may have to go with this approach. Though, I'd rather not to modify the code if it's possible.

Comment: Sounds like a [DailyWTF](http://thedailywtf.com/) candidate.

Comment: Short answer: no, there isn't.

Comment: Debugging this must be the biggest pain ever. Seriously: You're doing it wrong.

Comment: @stefan: I disagree. The file size here has nothing to do with code complexity. I just have a huge input, thus cause the file to be huge, the logic itself can be simple to debug.

Comment: @Patrick: Ok, maybe we are talking about different things. Do you mean struct as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language) ? If so, the usual way of writing structs has one item per line of code. Assuming that, are you seriously suggesting that you need a million (different) items in your struct? There is no way of having arays at all?

Comment: I am trying to imagine exactly what would require a million different variable names, what they would be, and how they would be used.  Try as I might, I just can't!  I'd love to see a 50-line sample of the struct.

Comment: That's not a struct.. that's a space station.

Comment: Sounds like a generated code (static data?). Think of modifying the compiler which generates this code, probably it is possible to split its output into several parts (unless they're cross-referenced).

Comment: @SK-logic Exactly, looks like generated code or massive copy paste. But that most definitively means, that arrays are possible. Nevertheless, it's still a good question. In one of my software projects, linking takes up to 30 seconds, so parallelization of the compiler would be very helpful.

Comment: @stefan, linking is even worse than compilation, you cannot split it into separate compilation units (unless you're generating many dynamic libraries, which is often not possible or not allowed), so the time is a function of a number of symbols in all the compilation units (and debugging information multiplies that complexity). I'd like to find any reasonable solution to this problem too, but not sure if such a solution even exist.

Comment: @SK-logic It's probably a hard problem but most likely not unsolvable. Afaik gcc will be fully migrated to C++ in the future, maybe it will be easier to identify possible parallelization with that.

Comment: @stefan, it is rather an `ld` or `gold` problem. Both are hopeless, and there are no emerging alternative linkers. I've played a bit with parallelisation of the code generation phase in `Clang`, but it did not worth the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is the struct definition that is over 1 million lines, then you're probably out of luck.

But if you're declaring a struct variable that is an array of that struct type that is many lines (or not an array but just a very big struct) then I would suggest placing the variable declaration in a separate .c file by itself and using the extern keyword in any other c file that needs to access it.  That way it will only need to be re-compiled when it changes.

For example if you had the following:

```
//Filename: onefile.c

struct _bigStruct{
  int type;
  char *name;
}bigStruct[] = {
  {  1, "One" },
  {  2, "Two" },
  {  3, "Three" },
  {  4, "Four" },
  ...
};

int someFunction(int j, int x)
{
  if (j == bigStruct[x])
     //do something
}
```

Then I would change it to the following:

```
//Filename: bigstruct.h
struct _bigStruct{
  int type;
  char *name;
};
```

and

```
//Filename: bigstruct.c
struct _bigStruct bigStruct[] = {
{  1, "One" },
{  2, "Two" },
{  3, "Three" },
{  4, "Four" },
...
};
```

and

```
//Filename: main.c
#include "bigstruct.h"

extern struct _bigStruct bigStruct[];

int someFunction(int j, int x)
{
  if (j == bigStruct[x].type)
     //do something
}
```